# error: cannot find symbol .setType(MultipartBody.FORM) symbol:variable MultipartBody exception while using okclient package in Android

Tags: java, android, api, file-upload, rest

I'm trying to upload the file from the android app to my rest API services using the OKclient package

But I am getting this error

> error: cannot find symbol .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
> symbol:variable MultipartBody location: class xxclass

Code:

```
public  void run(String urll, String fpath) throws Exception {
          MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("text/csv");
       // Use the imgur image upload API as documented at https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image
       RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
               .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
               .addFormDataPart("file", "square.csv",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),
                               new File(fpath)))
                               .build();

       Request request = new Request.Builder()
               .url(getAbsoluteUrl(urll))
               .post(requestBody)
               .build();

       try (Response response = client1.newCall(request).execute()) {
           if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

           System.out.println(response.body().string());
       }
   }
```

I'm using this **okhttp3** package -`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'` but still I'm facing same problems, Any idea?

Reference link: https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp